# Does one method call takes one CPU cycle?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cycles

Suppose we have following method

```
private int add(int num_1, int num_2) 
{
  return num_1+num+2;
}
```

Does calling this method consumes one cpu cycle ? 
As there are 1 billion cycles in 1 ghz.

Comment: The number of cycles/second is not directly related to the number of cycles required for a particular action. In any case, you many be interested in examining the 'assembly'-dump of such a C program/function or looking at the [function ABI / calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) to give a general idea of the different steps that are applied; and then there is the work done inside the function itself ..

Comment: that will depend a lot on the yielded assembly and CPU - if `num_1` and `num_2` are not in cache it might take more (usually will)

Answer (score -1):

No. consider the function call `sleep(5000)` which causes your code to pause for 5 seconds. That would take more than 1 clock cycle.